# Gatling: check binary response not empty

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm doing some tests with Gatling using Scala. I'm trying to check whether a response body that is returned is not empty.

I'm doing it like this:

```
def getImages: ChainBuilder = feed(credentials)
     .exec(http("Get Image")
     .get(GET_MY_URI)
     .queryParam("guid", "${branch}")
     .queryParam("t", "0.458654")
     .check(status.is(200))
     .check(bodyString.transform(_.size > 1).is(true)))
```

But it's not working. I get:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

Does somebody know how to achieve what I'm trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
.check(bodyString.transform(_.size > 1).is(true)))
```

with

```
.check(bodyBytes.exists)
```

All the DSL is explained here: https://gatling.io/docs/current/cheat-sheet/

Comment: Thank you it was far easier than what I was trying

Comment: The post is quite old but I found it looking for a similar problem, only I wanted to check that the response _is_ empty. However, it doesn't seem to work for me. `bodyBytes.exists` seems to be true even for an empty body. A combination of the OPs approach and yours seems to work: `bodyBytes.transform(_.length).is(0)`